# Compiling libssh for QNX (BB10)

Tags: cmake, blackberry-10, qnx, libssh

I'm trying to use [libssh](https://www.libssh.org) in my BlackBerry 10 project and have no idea how to compile it for this platform. Could you provide some steps to achieve this?

Comment: You did not see it in the compiler tool chain? Just add that library in the build profiler and see if that works. Adding build profiler will cause mkifs to include that library in the IFS image and you can access that during run time.